# DiVi - можно ли в данный конструктор добавить свой модуль

Tags: wordpress, конструктор

Может кто уже сталкивался с таким.
Нужно добавить в конструктор DIVI свой модуль или модуль другого автора. В документации ничего об этом не нашёл.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, зачем минусовать?

Comment: Возможно минус был из-за ошибок орфографии (пишу из клавиатуры где есть только анг буквы).

Comment: Поправил орфографию, минусить не будут)

Comment: Вот что вам нужно https://jonathanbossenger.com/building-your-own-divi-builder-modules/

Comment: Минусовал кто-то, не разобравшись. Отозвал уже свой минус после моего камента)

Comment: то что надо было, Спасибо огромное